# Using Powershell Get-ItemProperty through all of AD computers object

Tags: powershell, foreach, active-directory

I'm a complete newbie in Powershell (and programming as you may have guessed), I want to get the result of the following PS command for each of our AD computer object and print the result in a text file...but I'm completely lost. Does anyone have a lifeline I could hold on to?

```
Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" | Select-String -Pattern "mysoftwarename"
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ScriptBlock = {Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" | Select-String -Pattern "mysoftwarename"}
$Computers = (Get-ADComputers -filter * ).name
$Creds = (Get-Credential)

foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
    "`n`n$Computer`n" >> .\file.txt # "`n" just emulates Enter key press
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -Credential $Creds >> .\file.txt
}
```

This will work fine if you have all your computers online and PS remoting configured properly. Otherwise, it will require modifications.